# for loop inside query

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-postgres

I have this in mongo:

```
//fill QueryString
collection.find({"myID" : {$in:QueryString} },{}).toArray(function(err, Stuff) { 
... 
var flag = true;
for (var i=0; i<Stuff.length; i++) {

    //if statements .. alter flag
    // if Stuff[i].myField....
}

if (req.body.type == "myField") {

collection.update(
  { "my_id" : req.body.id },
  {$set : { "myField" : req.body.fileid }}, 
  function(err, result) {
  ....

 }
```

and I did this in postgresql:

```
pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {

        if (err) return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);

        client.query( "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE my_id = ANY ($1::varchar[])  ",[QueryString], function(err,Stuff) {


            var flag = true;
            for (var i=0; i<Stuff.rows.length; i++) {
             ...
            //if statements .. alter flag
            if (typeof(Stuff.rows[i].myField) === 'undefined' || ( (typeof(Stuff.rows[i].myField) !== 'undefined' && Stuff.rows[i].myField.length < 16 ) )) {

              if (req.body.my_ids[i] === req.body.id && req.body.type === "myField") {

              }else{
                flag = false;
              }
          }
            debug('flag:'+flag);              

}//end of for loop



 if (req.body.type === "anotherField") {

        client.query("UPDATE mytable  SET anotherField ='req.body.fileid' WHERE my_id = 'req.body.id'",  function(err, result)  {
    ....

    });//endof update

done();
});//end of first query
```

But , the for loop doesn't work as expected in the postgres.
I am not sure how to use for loop inside a query.

The problem is that the flag i every loop is false but it should be true.

=============== Using pg-promise ===================================

```
 dbPromise.tx(function (t) {
    return t.any("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE my_id = ANY  ($1::varchar[]) ",[QueryString])
        .then(function (Stuff) {


        var flag = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < Stuff.length; i++) {

        ...//if statements
        if (typeof(Stuff[i].myField === ....) 
        ...
        } //end of for loop

           var queries = Stuff.map(function (d) {

        if (req.body.type === "myField") {

              return t.none("UPDATE mytable  SET myField ='req.body.fileid' WHERE my_id = 'req.body.id'")

              debug("success: "+req.body.id);
              res.send({ user : req.user, message : "SUCCESS", my_id : req.body.id});     


      } else if (req.body.type === "anotherField") {
        ....
        }

        });
      return t.batch(queries);

})
    }) 
.then(function (Stuff) {
      //this is executed for every single update ,right?
         console.log("Hurrah!");
})
.catch(function (error) {

            console.log("ERROR:", error.message || error);
});
```

With this approach I am still in my initial problem.
The flag is false instead of true ( with regard with mongo ).

Finally, I am not sure about the `Stuff.map(function (d)`,about the `d`.Should I use `myField` instead?And if I have many fields like I do?

Comment: It should work as you have it.  I would set a breakpoint at the `var flag=true` line to see if you're getting back anything in Stuff as expected or if there's something wrong w/ your query.

Comment: @Paul:Ok, nice to hear that for loops are used like this.I updated my code.The problem is that the flag i every loop is false but it should be true.I have another query also (inside the first) . I am not sure if this is the problem?I am using `done()` only when finishing the first query.Thank you.

Comment: @George you should be using `done` after all queries have finished.

Comment: You say the loop doesn't work as expected but you don't say what it actually did.

Comment: @vitaly-t:Shouldn't I have to use `done()` right before the `});` of the first query?(inside the first query?). I tried also to put it outside `});` , when finishing the query ( and still inside the `pg.connect` but it doesn't finish the job (keeps running)

Comment: @HeadCode:The problem is that the flag i every loop is false but it should be true.

Comment: @George I think I was suggesting it in another question already that you should use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) for this as a much easier solution. Organizing a loop with `pg-promise` is very easy, but with native `node-postgres` it is a huge pain.

Comment: @vitaly-t:Thank you for your suggestions.Unfortunately,I couldn't manage to use appropriate the pg-promise ( regarding the other question ).You said that I could find posts here and documentation at the site ,but for me  they weren't enough :).

Comment: @George for this particular example I have published my answer ;)

Comment: pg-promise may help, or it may not.  Frankly, I don't find promises any more clear than callbacks.  The issue you're describing, I think the callback is a red herring.  You are determining, somewhere in code that you've not posted to us, that the `flag` variable should be set to true or false.  You set it true initially, which suggests to me that somewhere in your code you're setting it to false inadvertently.  Can you post that code?

Comment: @Paul:I updated my code ( the fisrt version ,no the "using pg-romises" ).Thanks

Comment: @Paul:I remind you that in mongodb version it works fine.I just hope , I translated ok the `collection.find({"myID" : {$in:QueryString} },{}).toArray(function(err, Stuff) { ` from mongo to postgres `        client.query( "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE my_id = ANY ($1::varchar[])  ",[QueryString], function(err,Stuff)`

Comment: @George I get that.  But the fact is that there's nothing in the mysql driver that will magically set your `flag` variable.  From what you wrote, your if statements are evaluating false for whatever reason, and therefore you're setting the flag false.  It might be as simple as a flub on the field names or the like, where you might have the right field names in your Mongo version.  Figure out why your code is evaluating those tests to false and that'll help you.

Comment: @Paul:The field names are exactly the same as in mongo.And since,I have translated correct the mongo commands to postgresql ,I don't know what remains to do .. :) .Thanks for the info.

Answer (score -1):

In order to complete your example, you should be using a transaction for multiple updates, to maintain the data integrity.

This is how the whole thing can be done with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), using a transaction:

```
db.tx(function (t) {
    return t.any("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE my_id = ...", [params])
        .then(function (data) {
            var queries = data.map(function (d) {
                if (/*need to update*/) {
                    // do any checks or manipulations for 'd';
                    return t.none("UPDATE myTable SET ...", [params])
                }
            });
            return t.batch(queries);
        })
})
    .then(function (data) {
        // all updates were successful;
        console.log("Hurrah!");
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // something failed;
        console.log("ERROR:", error.message || error);
    });
```

Comment: @vital-t:Thanks for the code.But , I can't figure where is my for loop ( inside the first query and before the second) and for example , I have `if (req.body.type === "anotherField") {

        client.query("UPDATE mytable  SET anot....` and after this if statement , I have another `if (req.body.type === "differentField") {

        client.query("UPDATE mytable  SET ...`.How these follow your example?

Comment: @George you can add any condition inside `data.map(function (d) {` callback. I have updated the example ;)

Comment: :I updated my post using your solution.I have still the same initial problem.Flag is false instead of true ( with comparison using mongo ).Also,in the `then` statement ,it is executed for every sinngle update query,right?How about an error?Where should I put a message for this?(for every update query) .The `catch` is for an error in the whole query , right?Finally , I am not sure about the ` Stuff.map(function (d)`,about the `d`.Should I use `myField` instead?And if I have many fields?

Comment: @George you need to make an effort at making the small changes yourself. Using StackOverflow to get somebody to write you all your code isn't gonna work well for you.

Comment: :But, I am writting code.Also,just , with no previous experience in nodejs,javascript,databases,even the small changes are hard!

Comment: @George if you want to get points for your questions, they must be precise and of value to others. So far you've been asking the exact opposite, some specific tasks that are of value to you only.